# How can I add Include to a non-clustered index in Entity Framwork Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following Entity:

```
public class ProductInventory
  {
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the product inventory identifier.</summary>
    /// <value>The product inventory identifier.</value>
    public long ProductInventoryId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the name.</summary>
    /// <value>The name.</value>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the axis calibration.</summary>
    /// <value>The axis calibration.</value>
    public double AxisCalibration { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the description.</summary>
    /// <value>The description.</value>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the create date.</summary>
    /// <value>The create date.</value>
    public DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }
  }
```

I need to create a non-clustered index for Name and Include the properties: AxisCalibration, Description.

Comment: I'm not sure how the editor can help you any more than it does. The tooltip on the button tells you exactly what goes in there, then the individual windows in the editor all state the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ForSqlServerInclude:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInventory>().HasIndex("Name").ForSqlServerInclude("AxisCalibration", "Description");
```

ForSqlServerInclude it works fine in lastest preview version 3.XXX.

Answer (score 0):

Since EF Core 5.0, you can use `IncludeProperties` in this way:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInventory>().HasIndex(x => x.Name).IncludeProperties(x => new { x.AxisCalibration, x.Description});
```